# formControlName in a child component

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I would like to create a custom input component and reuse it in my forms, but I am hitting an issue with formGroup and formControlName.

```
// Form
<form [formGroup]='loginForm'>
  <custom-input [myFormControlName]='email'></custom-input>
</form>

// CustomInput Component's Template
<input formControlName='myFormControlName'>
```

The problem appears to be that formControlName is expecting to be used with a FormGroup directive and since I am using formControlName in a sub-component it doesn't find the formControlName.. Anyone knows how to work around that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to implement [control value accessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) in your child component  read more here https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have a follow-up question. Since I want to use a pretty basic input do I need to define the interface of ControlValueAccessor or can I just use DefaultValueAccessor, if yes how?

Comment: I have never tried like this/ I usually implement control value accessor.

Comment: But you can do is extend DefaultValueAccessor. componentName extends DefaultValueAccessor and you will have all methods from default valueAccessor

Comment: It's an old answer, but I want to mention that the added link as a reference (https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html) is a different form concept. The example is for template driven forms and not reactive form which uses  `formContrlName`. But the question is about `formControlName`.

Answer (score 19):

Like @MassimoVariolo's [article](https://medium.com/@joshblf/using-child-components-in-angular-forms-d44e60036664) mentions, you can pass the form as an input to the child component.

Parent component html:

```html
<child-component [form]="form"></child-component>
```

Child component ts file:

```js
@Input() public form: FormGroup;
```

Child component html (you need the div with the `formGroup`, otherwise you'll get an error):

```html
<div [formGroup]="form">
    <input formControlName="myFormControlName"> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

I know two ways how it's possible to implement this behavior, one was mentioned by Sofia in the answer above, the second approach is to pass `formControl` down to the child component!

Inside parent component HTML

```
<child-component
   [control]="parentForm.get('form-control-name-you-want-to-pass-down')">
</child-component>
```

Inside `child-component`

```
@Input() control: AbstractControl = new FormControl();
```

Inside child component HTML

```
<input [formControl]="control" />
```

Comment: Awesome. This is the solution I was looking for. 
pass formControl down to the child component.  
it worked. thanks.

Comment: You might need to change the type from `AbstractControl` to `FormControl`, otherwise you'll get error `'AbstractControl' is missing the following properties from type 'FormControl': defaultValue, registerOnChange, registerOnDisabledChange, _applyFormState` (at least in Angular 13).

Answer (score 2):

You can consider reading this useful article: [Using Child Components in Angular Forms](https://medium.com/@joshblf/using-child-components-in-angular-forms-d44e60036664)

The core of the solution is to pass the formGroup instance to the child component and wrap it with the formGroup itself.

Comment: Looks good, seems much less verbose than using ControlValueAccessor